# Combine two regexp grammars in nltk

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, grammar

I'm defining a noun phrase using grammar in `nltk`. The example provided by `nltk` is:

```
grammar = "NP: {<DT>?<NNP>*<NN>}"
```

Then if I have a sentence like: `show me the Paris hospitals`, the library can detect the noun phrase:

```
>>> s
'show me the Paris hospitals'
>>> grammar = "NP: {<DT>?<NNP>*<NNS>}"
>>> nltk.RegexpParser(grammar).parse(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(s)))
Tree('S', [('show', 'VB'), ('me', 'PRP'), Tree('NP', [('the', 'DT'), ('Paris', 'NNP'), ('hospitals', 'NNS')])])
```

Now, the sentence can be written in another way: `show me the hospitals of Paris`, and hence I need to change the grammar to:

```
>>> grammar = "NP: {<DT>?<NNS><IN><NNP>}"
>>> s = "show me the hospitals in Paris"
>>> nltk.RegexpParser(grammar).parse(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(s)))
Tree('S', [('show', 'VB'), ('me', 'PRP'), Tree('NP', [('the', 'DT'), ('hospitals', 'NNS'), ('in', 'IN'), ('Paris', 'NNP')])])
```

How do I combine the two grammars in a unique one? I couldn't figure out the OR condition for the two grammars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define two NP rules in one grammar:

```py
grammar = """
NP: {<DT>?<NNP>*<NNS>}
NP: {<DT>?<NNS><IN><NNP>}
"""
```

or using `|` as the wanted `OR` condition:

```py
grammar = "NP: {<DT>?<NNP>*<NNS>|<DT>?<NNS><IN><NNP>}"
```

Full example:

```py
import nltk

sentence_1 = 'show me the Paris hospitals'
sentence_2 = "show me the hospitals in Paris"

grammar_1 = """
NP: {<DT>?<NNP>*<NNS>}
NP: {<DT>?<NNS><IN><NNP>}
"""
parser_1 = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar_1)

grammar_2 = "NP: {<DT>?<NNP>*<NNS>|<DT>?<NNS><IN><NNP>}"
parser_2 = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar_2)

for s in sentence_1, sentence_2:
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
    pos_tags = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
    print(parser_1.parse(pos_tags))
    print(parser_2.parse(pos_tags))

# outputs the same for both parsers:
# (S show/VB me/PRP (NP the/DT Paris/NNP hospitals/NNS))
# (S show/VB me/PRP (NP the/DT Paris/NNP hospitals/NNS))
# (S show/VB me/PRP (NP the/DT hospitals/NNS) in/IN Paris/NNP)
# (S show/VB me/PRP (NP the/DT hospitals/NNS) in/IN Paris/NNP)
```

([link to the documentation](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.chunk.regexp.html?highlight=regexpparser#nltk.chunk.regexp.RegexpParser))

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I compare the result from the combined grammar to `NP: {<DT>?<NNS><IN><NNP>}`, I found a difference.
Specifically, the above grammar (part of the combined grammar) produces:
`(S show/VB me/PRP (NP the/DT hospitals/NNS in/IN Paris/NNP))`. 
Here the tree NP contains `Paris`, while the NP of the combined grammar does not contain Paris. 
Is there a way to overcome it?

Comment: "The patterns of a clause are executed in order." (ff., see [linked documentation](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.chunk.regexp.html?highlight=regexpparser#nltk.chunk.regexp.RegexpParser)). You can switch the order of the rules to get the same results. FWIW: There is also the [trace flag](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.chunk.regexp.html?highlight=regexpparser#nltk.chunk.regexp.RegexpParser.parse) for the parser. Maybe this could help a bit, too. E.g. `parser.parse(pos_tags, trace=2)`.

Comment: Switching the orders works for me. I accepted the answer.